# How to use airflow secret backend with aws secret manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, devops, airflow-webserver, airflow-api

I have installed the airflow 1.10.15 in standalone server & trying to integrate aws secret manager with it but values are not coming.

I have added `backend = airflow.contrib.secrets.aws_secrets_manager.SecretsManagerBackend` and `backend_kwargs = {"connections_prefix": "airflow/test}` under secrets in airflow.cfg. Also, i have added role to ec2 server which has secret manager read/write access but still it is not taking value from secret manager.

Comment: Have you followed AWS documentation?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/connections-secrets-manager.html

Comment: I am not using MWAA but i did all the steps in airflow cfg

Answer (score 0):

You can use the airflow secret backend with the aws secret manager by creating a new airflow secret and then setting the backend to awssecretmanager.